# Read HttpClient Stream Asynchronously

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I wrote below async method to download file stream from **WebApi**. But while awaiting result at `networkStrm = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(_downloadRestUrl);`

> Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing
>   connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. The underlying
>   connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.

```
    async internal Task<Stream> DownloadAsync(string _downloadRestUrl)
    {
        Stream networkStrm = null;
        try
        {
            var baseUrl = GetBaseUrl(_downloadRestUrl);

            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            httpClient.BaseAddress = baseUrl;
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"));

            networkStrm = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(_downloadRestUrl);
            networkStrm.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return networkStrm;
    }
```

Comment: Is the url working with a different client? Could any of the solutions in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582036/an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host) work for you?

Comment: @mot Url is fine. Same code if I write non-async version it works fine.

Comment: Please edit your question and add info about how it works non-async, this really changes the kind of answers you are going to get.

Comment: Could you use Wireshark or Fiddler to see if there is a difference between the successful and unsuccessful requests?