# Golang TCP error wsarecv

Tags: tcp, go

I am writing an app which listens `tcp connection` (see [this example](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-dev/UXJ_a03MhcU/HcTwv224qpUJ)) . When a `tcp connection`  disconnected I got error **`read tcp ip_server.:port1->ip_client:port2: wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.`** 
I expected error `EOF` and timeout(for `conn.SetReadDeadline()`) and tried to catch error with this code:

```
if err != nil {     
    log.Println("getting error from listener")
    // I thought, listener can continue work another cases
    if neterr, ok := err.(net.Error); ok && neterr.Timeout() || err == io.EOF {
        log.Println("Closing connection...")
        break // connection will be closed 
    }
}
```

Anyone knows about this error? Do you know how to catch this error and when this error will occured ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: Not with Go but the same kind of error : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582036/an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The usual cause of this error is that you sent data over a connection which had already been closed by the peer. In other words, an application protocol error.

Comment: @Ulug'bekRo'zimboyev, two easy ways to find out: a) look at the Go `net` package source or b) use `log.Printf("%T %+v", err, err)` to format/print both the full type and full information contained in `err` when it occurs, that will tell you what code you need to replace the `Printf` with.

Comment: Did you find a type for this message?

Comment: I get `*net.OpError read tcp ip_server.:port1->ip_client:port2: wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.`, so the type of the message should be `*net.OpError`.

Comment: @Ulug'bekRo'zimboyev Ultimately it is ECONNRESET. What that maps to in *go* is unknown to me, but you might look it up.

Comment: This happens to me sometimes when I forward port of Argo server by
```kubectl -n argo-events port-forward deployment/argo-server 2746:2746```
How to fix it?