# Sending email via Python and Google SMTP server

Tags: python, email, smtp, mail-server

My email is: `sarahconnor@gmail.com`

I would like to send an email from `johnconnor@skynet.com` to mine.

I don't want to login remotely to my gmail account to send an email.

**This is what I need:**

I'm Sarah Connor, and I want to receive in my mailbox ( `sarahconnor@gmail.com` ), an e-mail from `johnconnor@skynet.com` ...

So I've use this script to do so:

```
import requests
import smtplib

from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

COMMASPACE = ', '

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = 'Our family reunion'
fromm = "johnconnor@skynet.com"
to = "sarahconnor@gmail.com"
msg['From'] = fromm
msg['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(to)
msg.preamble = 'Our family reunion'

requests.get("http://smtp.gmail.com", verify=False)
s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
s.starttls()
s.login('sarahconnor@gmail.com', 'mypassword12345') #here I login to the SMTP server from Google to be able to send emails...
s.sendmail(fromm, to, msg.as_string())
s.close()
```

I have the following error:

```
raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'))
```

And as seen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582036/an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host), it doesn't seem that I'm having any of that issues.

Does anyone knows how can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this sends a mail **from** a gmail account to any other account

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText


class GmailHandler():
    """
    IMPORTANT NOTE:
    in order to access a gmail account with this handler,
    your account needs 'foreign-access' enabled (follow these steps):
    login to the account
    go here--> https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha
    press 'Continue'
    Done.
    """

    def __init__(self, gmail, password):
        self.gmail = gmail
        self.password = password

    def send_mail(self, receivers, subject, text):

        if not isinstance(receivers, list):
            receivers = [receivers]

        # Send the message via our own SMTP server, but don't include the envelope header
        smtp = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
        smtp.ehlo()
        smtp.starttls()
        smtp.ehlo()
        smtp.login(self.gmail, self.password)

        for receiver in receivers:

            msg = MIMEText(text)
            msg['Subject'] = subject
            msg['From'] = self.gmail
            msg['To'] = receiver
            smtp.sendmail(self.gmail, receiver, str(msg))

        smtp.quit()
```

Comment: ok thanks, but that's not what I need:( I need to send an email from another email, to my email...not from a gmail account. As I said: "I don't want to login remotely to my gmail account to send an email."

Answer (score 1):

Use `smtplib.SMTP` instead of `smtplib.SMTP_SSL`.