# Server issue when client disconnects

Tags: c#, asynchronous, server

```
        public class AsynchronousSocketListener
        {
            // Thread signal.  
            public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

            public AsynchronousSocketListener()
            {
            }

            public static void StartListening()
            {
                // Data buffer for incoming data.  
                byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];

                // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.  
                // The DNS name of the computer  
                // running the listener is "host.contoso.com".  
                //IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
                // IPAddress ipAddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
                // IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 8017);
                //
                // IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
                // IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
                IPAddress ipAddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
                IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 8017);

                // Create a TCP/IP socket.  
                Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                    SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

                // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.  
                try
                {
                    listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
                    listener.Listen(100);

                    while (true)
                    {
                        // Set the event to nonsignaled state.  
                        allDone.Reset();

                        // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.  
                        Console.WriteLine("Connecting to StrangeLanes.com...");
                        listener.BeginAccept(
                            new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                            listener);

                        // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.  
                        allDone.WaitOne();
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                }

                Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
                Console.Read();

            }

            public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
            {
                // Signal the main thread to continue.  
                allDone.Set();

                // Get the socket that handles the client request.  
                Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
                Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

                // Create the state object.  
                StateObject state = new StateObject();
                state.workSocket = handler;
                handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                    new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
            }

            public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Msg rechived");
                String content = String.Empty;

                // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket  
                // from the asynchronous state object.  
                StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
                Socket handler = state.workSocket;

                // Read data from the client socket.  

                int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

                if (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.  
                    state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
                        state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

                    // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read   
                    // more data.  
                    content = state.sb.ToString();
                    if (content.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
                    {
                        if (content.IndexOf("Login") > -1)
                        {
                            // All the data has been read from the   
                            // client. Display it on the console.  
                            Console.WriteLine("Read {0} bytes from socket. \n Data : {1}",
                                content.Length, content);
                            // Echo the data back to the client.
                            string Str = content.Substring(6, content.Length - 11);
                            Console.WriteLine(Str);
                            string[] Nn = Str.Split(':');
                            string User = Nn[0];
                            string Pass = Nn[1];
                            int Pp = FindInArray(User_Names, User);
                            if (Pp>=0)
                            {
                                if (User_Passwords[Pp]==Pass)
                                {
                                    Send(handler, "Login-ACPT:Current_Version>" + Current_Version);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Send(handler, "Msg:Login Failed Wrong Password");
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Send(handler, "Msg:Unknown user :/");
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        if (content.IndexOf("Req_Version") > -1)
                        {
                            Send(handler, "Current_Version>" + Current_Version);
                        }
                        //message done redy for next one 
                            state.sb.Clear();
                         handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                          new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Not all data received. Get more.  
                        handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                        new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
                    }
                }
            }

            private static void Send(Socket handler, String data)
            {
                // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.  
                byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

                // Begin sending the data to the remote device.  
                handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
                    new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
            }

            private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Retrieve the socket from the state object.  
                    Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

                    // Complete sending the data to the remote device.  
                    int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
                    Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to client.", bytesSent);

                    //handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                    //handler.Close();

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                }
            }

            public static int Main(String[] args)
            {
                StartListening();
                return 0;
            }
        }


    }
}
```

This is my code based on: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx

I removed the disconnect on SendCallBack:

```
 //handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                        //handler.Close();
```

to prevent it from only be able to get one message from my client and added this to the when message is achieved from client:

```
 state.sb.Clear();
 handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
 new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
```

However this line:

```
int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);
```

Causes a crash when a client shuts down (break connection) Anyone know how to do this without error?

Comment: What error message do you receive?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll  : An existing connection was forced down from the existing host.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582036/an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host)