# An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host in authorize.net

Tags: c#, authorize.net

I'm trying to test some of the samples for authorize.net in c# located at this url https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sample-code-csharp/tree/40526f6e763825447ff934ac03eff464bd5dad8a

Whenever I'm launching some of the samples I'm getting this error:

> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>   error code: 10054

This is the exception I'm getting:

[image]

Comment: Who is the remote host? Does it know you? What *exactly* is the mysterious code which is throwing the error?

Comment: @AndrewMorton this is where the actual exception happening https://i.gyazo.com/e60bb4c2efd110205f92f8ccdc32930b.png I'm just trying to run one sample so I can see the output. How should the remote host know me? Can you please provide some advice. Thanks

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please post code as text, not as a picture.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582036/an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of the .Net framework are you using? If you are using .Net framework 4.5, try adding the following at the beginning of the function where you make a webrequest:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```