# Not able to run Xamarin Android Native App no errors but deploy failed in Windows 10

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I have seen other posts of same kind of error but probably on different vs and windows versions. Tried few things from the posts but nothing worked.

Just created a blank xamarin android app without any code written in it.
Did a build, rebuild, clean, restarted system, restarted visual studio, running vs as admin all possible things but nothing worked out.

Below is the message from output window.

```
2>Done building project "App1.csproj".
2>Build succeeded.
2>An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
2>
2>Deploy failed on Motorola XT1068
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I am running Visual Studio 2017 with Version 15.4.0 on Windows 10 operating system.

Comment: Have you tried this on a different device such as an emulator? I would guess this falls under the same territory here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582036/an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host

Comment: Is the phone in developer mode?

Comment: yes I am able to run the apps from android studio installed in same system for the same set of devices...

Comment: Could you please try that on the emulator installed by VS?

Comment: emulator I tried now its working but not on mobile devices gives the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> emulator I tried now its working but not on mobile devices gives the same error

There are a few things you can try:

1. Please check if the target API level of your app is identical to your device's system's API level. You can modify the app's API level by `Right click project-> properties->Android Manifest->Target Android Version`.
2. If it doesn't work, please try override your android `sdk` to the sdk that your android studio is using, you can override the sdk by `Tools->Options->Xamarin->Android Settings->Android SDK Location`

Comment: Thanks, my app was targetting API level 30 but my emulator was under API level 29.
Don't forget to Clean and Rebuild.