# Netsuite restlet calls from .Net Api started to give errors

Tags: .net, netsuite, webapi

I am using token based authentication for calling netsuite restlets from my .Net WebAPIs.
It has been working well, but since yesterday I started getting this below error on Netsuite sandbox. I don’t see any code change that could have resulted to this. Can anyone point me to the right direction?

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a TLS issue as their sandbox has removed TLS 1.0/1.1

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46944838/266509

Answer (score 0):

I figure that you probably are looking for a Netsuite / Suitescript specific answer but in-case it helps, the following is a thread on the exception string you are reading:

[An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582036/an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host)