# SSL/TLS secure channel error while downloading using c# webclient

Tags: c#, ssl

all of a sudden my existing code started failing to download the file (https://www.cftc.gov/files/dea/history/com_disagg_txt_2024.zip). while searching for a solution I found this link ([Exception when downloading file using webclient (c#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49458475/exception-when-downloading-file-using-webclient-c)) where similar issue was discussed. Tried to use the same code. Seeing the error "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" with same code. Please see my code below setup using a c# console app.I used .Net 4.7.2 runtime.

Please could you help me resolve this.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WebClient_DownLoad(new Uri("https://www.cftc.gov/files/dea/history/com_disagg_txt_2024.zip"), "com_disagg_txt_2024.zip");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void WebClient_DownLoad(Uri URI, string FileName)
        {
            using (WebClient webclient = new WebClient())
            {
                ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072; 

                webclient.CachePolicy = new System.Net.Cache.RequestCachePolicy(System.Net.Cache.RequestCacheLevel.BypassCache);
                webclient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0");
                webclient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "ext/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
                webclient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-US,en;q=0.8");
                webclient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate;q=0.8");
                webclient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl, "no-cache");
                webclient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.KeepAlive, "keep-alive");
                webclient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

                webclient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(WebClient_DownloadComplete);
                webclient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(WebClient_DownloadProgress);

                webclient.DownloadFileAsync(URI, FileName);
            };
        }

        private static void WebClient_DownloadProgress(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            string Result = string.Format("Received: {0}  Total: {1}  Percentage: {2}",
                                 e.BytesReceived, e.TotalBytesToReceive, e.ProgressPercentage);
            //Update the UI
            Console.WriteLine(Result);
        }

        private static void WebClient_DownloadComplete(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!e.Cancelled)
            {
                if (e.Error != null)
                    // Update the UI: transfer completed.
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Error.Message);
            }
            else
            {
                // Update the UI: transfer Cancelled.
                Console.WriteLine("Cancelled");
            }
        }
```

Comment: you should stop using webclient and migrate to httpclient, you can download restsharp client from nuget

Answer (score 2):

This server is TLS 1.3 only, i.e. does not support TLS 1.2 or lower - see [the SSLLabs report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.cftc.gov).

> I used .Net 4.7.2 runtime.

Net 4.7.x does not support TLS 1.3, it is only available with Net 4.8. To cite from [Transport Layer Security (TLS) best practices with the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls):

> For TLS 1.3, target .NET Framework 4.8 or later.

Comment: I updated the .Net framework run time to 4.8 and used TLS1.3. Now the error message is changed to "The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm". Please could you advise.

Comment: @user965291: This is a different problem, please ask it is a new question with enough detail.