# Kubernetes: readinessProbes failing but the livelinessProbe is succeeding with the same settings

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a livelinessProbe configured for my pod which does a http-get on path on the same pod and a particular port. It works perfectly. But, if I use the same settings and configure a readinessProbe it fails with the below error.

> Readiness probe failed: wsarecv: read tcp :50578->:80: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Actually after certain point I even see the liveliness probes failing. not sure why . Liveliness probe succeeding should indicate that the kube-dns is working fine and we're able to reach the pod from the node. Here's the readinessProbe for my pod's spec

```yaml
readinessProbe:  
        httpGet:  
          path: /<path> # -> this works for livelinessProbe  
          port: 80  
        initialDelaySeconds: 30  
        periodSeconds: 10  
        timeoutSeconds: 10
```

Does anyone have an idea what might be going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it has anything to do with `kube-dns` or `coredns`. The most likely cause here is that your pod/container/application is crashing or stop serving requests.

Seems like this timeline:

- Pod/container comes up.
- Liveliness probe passes ok.
- Some time passes.
- Probably app crash or error.
- Readiness fails.
- Liveliness probe fails too.

More information about what that error means here: 
[An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582036/an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response :)

But, without the readiness probe, livelinessprobe never failed. its only when I added the readinessProbe things started to fail.

Comment: Did you check everything is running fine in your pod?

Comment: If I don't setup the readinessProbe in the pod, everything runs fine. I'm able to call the service that I deployed, the livelinessProbes are succeeding too. 
but once I setup the readinessProbe, I'm not able to run my service on that pod as well. when I run wget, it keeps failing.

Comment: Actually, my readinessprobe takes around 2-3 min for the first time. So, I had the timeout to be 180. But, after a while(around 2 min) it fails with the error
"wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

Comment: It may be an issue with your app. I would suggest you shell into the pod and check for log files, or check the stdout logs with `kubectl logs <pod-name>`