# An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host in Azure Face API

Tags: azure, api, face

I'm facing an issue in the Azure Face API. It was working fine earlier.
Facing the below error 
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Could you please let me know what could be the reason for the same.

```
try
            {
                await faceServiceClient.DeletePersonGroupAsync(_groupId);
            }
            catch (Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Common.ClientException exC)
            {

            }
            catch (FaceAPIException ex)
            {

            }
```

Comment: Please show us some more (relevante) code. For instance: did you override the `ServiceHost` property on the FaceServiceClient? And which version are you using?

Comment: Yes, i've overridden the Service Host property and using the version 1.2.5.0.

Comment: What have you override the ServiceHost to? I'm guessing something _without_ https? 'Cause that might be the issue.

Comment: No it is with https.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582036/an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host)