# How to solve the problem, "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host." while sending mail from Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, smtp, gmail, swiftmailer

I am trying to send an **email from Laravel**, but it's giving an **ErrorException**. I am using **gmail** with generated application password.

I've tried both the protocols, SSL and TLS with their respective ports. Also tried making changes in options array in `Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer`

```
verify_peer => false,
verify_peer_name => false
```

The settings in my environment file are:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=myApplicationPassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

The **error** I received is:

> fwrite(): send of 17 bytes failed with errno=10054 
>       An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. 
>       *in StreamBuffer.php line 240*
>
> `at HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'fwrite(): send of 17 bytes failed with errno=10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ', 'D:\\xampp2\\htdocs\\express\\vendor\\swiftmailer\\swiftmailer\\lib\\classes\\Swift\\Transport\\StreamBuffer.php', 240, array('bytes' => 'HELO [IPv6:::1] ', 'bytesToWrite' => 17, 'totalBytesWritten' => 0))`

I've also filled **from** and **reply_to** array with my Email Address and Name in `config/mail.php`

The code for sending mail is:

```
Mail::to($user->email)->send(new WelcomeMail);
```

Kindly tell me, the reason behind this error, can it be solved without hacking core files? What **alternatives** are available to me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2582070/2693543