# How to fix add-migration failing with transport-level error

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

When I try to add a string field to a domain object, and then I run add-migration, I get the following error:

> PM> add-migration add-field-to-contact
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, UInt32 error)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniSyncOverAsync()
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadNetworkPacket()
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryPrepareBuffer()
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadByteArray(Byte[] buff, Int32 offset, Int32 len, Int32& totalRead)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadString(Int32 length, String& value)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryReadSqlStringValue(SqlBuffer value, Byte type, Int32 length, Encoding encoding, Boolean isPlp, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryReadSqlValue(SqlBuffer value, SqlMetaDataPriv md, Int32 length, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, SqlCommandColumnEncryptionSetting columnEncryptionOverride, String columnName)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadColumnData()
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadColumnInternal(Int32 i, Boolean readHeaderOnly)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadColumn(Int32 i, Boolean setTimeout, Boolean allowPartiallyReadColumn)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetString(Int32 i)
>      at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
>      at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.History.HistoryRepository.GetPendingMigrations(IEnumerable`1 localMigrations)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.GetPendingMigrations()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Scaffold(String migrationName, String namespace, Boolean ignoreChanges)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.MigrationScaffolder.Scaffold(String migrationName, Boolean ignoreChanges)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.Scaffold(MigrationScaffolder scaffolder)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.Run()
>      at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
>      at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Scaffold(String migrationName, String language, String rootNamespace, Boolean ignoreChanges)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.Execute(String name, Boolean force, Boolean ignoreChanges)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
>   ClientConnectionId:5682a620-7a08-4c70-815f-591d8bf49ab6
>   Error Number:10054,State:0,Class:20
>   A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)

I have tried the following:

- I checked all connection strings.
- I tried adding the migration from another machine (failed with same error).
- I tried adding a migration to the same server but to a restored database (failed with same error).
- I tried adding a migration on a different application to the same server, different database (Worked perfect).
- I restored my live db which is a few migrations behind my dev environment. The first update-database I called worked. all calls after failed with the same error.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582036/an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host
In particular you might have a circular reference as mentioned by one of the answers.

Comment: @gilliduck thanks for your suggestion. my last successful migration was yesterday morning a few hours before all of the above started. if there was a circular reference i would have seen this behavior sooner. However, after seeing your response, i have gone through all my domain models to be sure.

Comment: The mapping between the Entity Classes and the Database are not matching.  You need to update the Entity Model to match the current database.  The mapping is not forward/backwards compatible.  You need a different Entity Model for each version of the database.  To prevent these errors it is recommended that you have a database version and check the version with the version of the c# code.

Comment: I ended up  pulling a copy of the live db to my local machine and reapplied the updates. now everything is working again. I then did the same with my dev server (again) and that also worked. I have no idea what caused the issue but it seems to be resolved.