# Django An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am googling a lot to find the solution. Maybe this is windows or python bug. I am here for getting help. It is creating problem while debuging.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 332, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 258, in send_preamble
    self._write(('Server: %s\r\n' % self.server_software).encode('iso-8859-1'))
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 803, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
[19/Apr/2019 14:31:19] ERROR [django.server:154] "GET /static/node_modules/metronic-theme-classic/assets/media/logos/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 52183)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 332, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 258, in send_preamble
    self._write(('Server: %s\r\n' % self.server_software).encode('iso-8859-1'))
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 803, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 116, in handle_error
    super().handle_error()
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 654, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 364, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 724, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 171, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 194, in handle_one_request
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 111, in close
    super().close()
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
----------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 333, in send_headers
    self._write(bytes(self.headers))
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 803, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
[19/Apr/2019 14:31:21] ERROR [django.server:154] "GET /static/node_modules/metronic-theme-classic/assets/media/logos/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 52185)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 333, in send_headers
    self._write(bytes(self.headers))
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 803, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 116, in handle_error
    super().handle_error()
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 654, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 364, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 724, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 171, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 194, in handle_one_request
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 111, in close
    super().close()
  File "C:\Users\azad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582036/an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host)

Comment: This is a python bug, will be fixed in version 3.7.4. See more [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/9713)