# System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: wcf, connection

issue:WCF application, when the NetTCP client calls the server-side remote method (there are many remote methods, the server-side cpu/memory is normal). The following errors occur very occasionally every day.

error info:

> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:01:00'. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout)

Environment: **Windows 2008 R2, .NET Framework 4.5**

Service setting:
`NetTcpBinding: listenBacklog="1000",maxConnections="1000" ReceiveTimeout="12:00:00",percall ServiceThrottling : maxConcurrentCalls="1000",percall DataContractSerializer :maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"`

Client setting: `TcpBinding CloseTimeout="00:01:00" OpenTimeout="00:00:10" ReceiveTimeout="00:01:00" SendTimeout="00:01:00" TransferMode="Buffered" ListenBacklog="1000" MaxBufferPoolSize="1073741824" MaxBufferSize="1073741824" MaxConnections="100" MaxReceivedMessageSize="1073741824" UseDefaultWebProxy="false" HostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"> ReaderQuotas MaxArrayLength="163840000" MaxBytesPerRead="1048576" MaxDepth="256" MaxNameTableCharCount="163840000" MaxStringContentLength="163840000"`

Additional info:

I've seen this question: [An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582036/an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host)

Comment: I am not sure what the question is about, because of the additional posted info.

Comment: Please don't copy accepted answer from other question into your new question, this causes confusion - if you have some question, doubt, remarks, etc. to that answer just put link and write something about it