# Azure Cosmos DB - intermittent MongoConnectionException / IOException / SocketException

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using Azure Cosmos DB 4.0 with MongoDB C# Driver 2.10.4.

Most of the times the queries work fine, but I'm getting intermittent errors like this:

> MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while sending a message to the server.
> System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginSend(...
> at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.BeginWrite
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.BeginWrite
> at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartWriting
> at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessWrite
> at System.Net.Security._SslStream.BeginWrite

When that error happens the call takes 10-25 seconds before failing.

I'm building the MongoClient with `new MongoClient(MongoClientSettings.FromConnectionString(cnstr))` and I was using the connectionstring with these arguments `?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb&retrywrites=false`.

I tried with `retryWrites=true` (as per Azure Support suggestion) but that didn't help.

I tried different settings and that didn't work either (`connect=direct`, `maxIdleTimeMS=30000`, `serverSelectionTimeout=5000ms`, `socketTimeout=10000ms`).

**What's causing those exceptions?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The fix was to set/force TLS 1.2** (based on [this Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-mongodb-dotnet)):

```cs
//return new MongoClient(connectionString);
var settings = MongoClientSettings.FromConnectionString(connectionString);
settings.SslSettings = new SslSettings()
{
    EnabledSslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12
};
return new MongoClient(settings);
```

Looks like although my connection string had `ssl=true`, it wasn't enough to work on some servers (the error is intermittent). The same underlying error can usually be fixed by [forcing TLS 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50746109/3606250) so I assumed that in Mongo it could be the same issue - and it really fixed the problem.