# Why do I get ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host?

Tags: python, automation, google-chrome-headless, pyppeteer

```
Exception in callback _ProactorBasePipeTransport._call_connection_lost(None)
handle: <Handle _ProactorBasePipeTransport._call_connection_lost(None)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 81, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 162, in _call_connection_lost
    self._sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Whats the common cause of this error? I get this error intermittently at many places in my code.

Comment: This might help you with further investigation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582036/an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host

Comment: I suppose this is a [bug of asyncio](https://bugs.python.org/issue43253)