# Why does Python requests keep giving me this error? "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, python-requests, binance

I am attempting to send a request to Binance api (crypto exchange) for the latest price of a specific symbol of crypto every ten seconds. However after between 5 to 20 hours it stops working throwing this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\nrspa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
> line 703, in urlopen
> httplib_response = self._make_request(   File "C:\Users\nrspa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
> line 386, in _make_request
> self._validate_conn(conn)   File "C:\Users\nrspa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
> line 1040, in *validate_conn
> conn.connect()   File "C:\Users\nrspa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py",
> line 416, in connect
> self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(   File "C:\Users\nrspa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl*.py",
> line 449, in ssl_wrap_socket
> ssl_sock = *ssl_wrap_socket_impl(   File "C:\Users\nrspa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl*.py",
> line 493, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
> return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)   File
> "C:\Users\nrspa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py",
> line 512, in wrap_socket
> return self.sslsocket_class._create(   File "C:\Users\nrspa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py",
> line 1070, in _create
> self.do_handshake()   File "C:\Users\nrspa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py",
> line 1341, in do_handshake
> self._sslobj.do_handshake() ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\nrspa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py",
> line 440, in send
> resp = conn.urlopen(   File "C:\Users\nrspa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
> line 785, in urlopen
> retries = retries.increment(   File "C:\Users\nrspa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py",
> line 550, in increment
> raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)   File "C:\Users\nrspa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py",
> line 769, in reraise
> raise value.with_traceback(tb)   File "C:\Users\nrspa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
> line 703, in urlopen
> httplib_response = self._make_request(   File "C:\Users\nrspa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
> line 386, in _make_request
> self._validate_conn(conn)   File "C:\Users\nrspa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
> line 1040, in *validate_conn
> conn.connect()   File "C:\Users\nrspa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py",
> line 416, in connect
> self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(   File "C:\Users\nrspa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl*.py",
> line 449, in ssl_wrap_socket
> ssl_sock = *ssl_wrap_socket_impl(   File "C:\Users\nrspa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl*.py",
> line 493, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
> return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)   File
> "C:\Users\nrspa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py",
> line 512, in wrap_socket
> return self.sslsocket_class._create(   File "C:\Users\nrspa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py",
> line 1070, in _create
> self.do_handshake()   File "C:\Users\nrspa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py",
> line 1341, in do_handshake
> self._sslobj.do_handshake() urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing
> connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054,
> None))
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "c:\Users\nrspa\Desktop\CryptoBot v2.6 (24h)\main (market).py", line
> 113, in 
> CB.main()   File "c:\Users\nrspa\Desktop\CryptoBot v2.6 (24h)\main (market).py", line 68, in main
> self.array = self.create_array()   File "c:\Users\nrspa\Desktop\CryptoBot v2.6 (24h)\main (market).py", line
> 46, in create_array
> self.array.append(self.get_price())   File "c:\Users\nrspa\Desktop\CryptoBot v2.6 (24h)\main (market).py", line
> 22, in get_price
> response = requests.get(url, headers = {"User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
> Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"})   File
> "C:\Users\nrspa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py",
> line 75, in get
> return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\nrspa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py",
> line 61, in request
> return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\nrspa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py",
> line 529, in request
> resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)   File "C:\Users\nrspa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py",
> line 645, in send
> r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\nrspa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py",
> line 501, in send
> raise ConnectionError(err, request=request) requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.',
> ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly
> closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))

Also note that this is my code (it is part of a class) it gets the price from Binance every 10 seconds until the desired array length is reached, at which point it processes the data:

```
import json
import requests
import time

def get_price(self):
    url = f"https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol={self.symbol}" 
    response = requests.get(url, headers = {"User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"})
    json_response = json.loads(response.text)
    return float(json_response['price'])

def create_array(self):
    i = len(self.array)
    if i < self.array_len:
        while i < self.array_len:
            time.sleep(self.time_interval)
            self.array.append(self.get_price())
            i = i + 1
        return self.array
    else:
        main()
```

Comment: There's a [C# Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582036/an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host) about the same error, and there's some general suggestions that aren't language-specific. Does that help at all?

Comment: The answer is right there in your stack trace: "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host." Binance is closing your connection. Considering your code doesn't appear account for their API limits (https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#limits) whatsoever, I would hazard a guess that you're exceeding them.

Comment: Yeah so I am making like 9000 request per 24h where the limit is like 100000. I will check out the c# answers thanks for your help!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You should be able to get the proper rate limiting info from the /api/v3/exchangeInfo endpoint and then you could use that to automatically limit request speed. What would help you troubleshoot would be to catch the exception and see what the actual HTTP response code is from the server.

Comment: I do see that you should be able to do 1,200 req/minute with your particular setup, actually, so perhaps that's not the problem. Definitely would check that return code if I were you.

Comment: Okay I apologise but I am an amateur programmer, so how would I catch the actual code response from the server? When you say check the return code do you mean make sure that 'price' actually exists in the dictionary?

Answer (score 3):

The issue can be caused by a "disagreement" between both sides. It can be that the connection timed out or the server closed it.

**The fix is to catch this exception and open the connection again.**

Comment: Okay I will give that a shot and let you know how it goes, thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks mate your an absolute legend, this fixed it for me

Comment: I tried dealing with this error by using try/except catching in my handle_socket_message (ThreadedWebsocketManager) function but I the error is still stopping my script, could you elaborate some on where and how you are catching the exception? thanks

Comment: you need to use except ConnectionResetError: