# Connection problems while using Parallel.ForEach Loop

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I have a `foreach` loop which is responsible for executing a certain set of statements. A part of that is to save an image from a URL to Azure storage. I have to do this for a large set of data. To achieve the same I have converted the `foreach` loop into a `Parallel.ForEach` loop.

```cs
 Parallel.ForEach(listSkills, item =>
 {
     // some business logic
     var b = getImageFromUrl(item.Url);
     Stream ms = new MemoryStream(b);

     saveImage(ms);
     // more business logic
 });

 private static byte[] getByteArray(Stream input)
 {
   using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
   {
     input.CopyTo(ms);
     return ms.ToArray();
   }
 }

 public static byte[] getImageFromUrl(string url)
 {
    HttpWebRequest request = null;
    HttpWebResponse response = null;
    byte[] b = null;
    request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    if (request.HaveResponse)
    {
      if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
       {
          Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
          b = getByteArray(receiveStream);
       }
    }

    return b;
 }

 public static void saveImage(Stream fileContent)
 {
  fileContent.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
  byte[] bytes = getByteArray(fileContent);
  var blob = null;
  blob.UploadFromByteArrayAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length).Wait();
 }
```

Although there are  instances when I am getting the below error and the image is not getting saved.

> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Also sharing the StackTrace :

```
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Span`1 buffer)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<FillBufferAsync>d__183`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<ReadAsyncInternal>d__181`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.Stream.Read(Span`1 buffer)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.Read(Span`1 destination)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ContentLengthReadStream.Read(Span`1 buffer)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpBaseStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.Stream.CopyTo(Stream destination, Int32 bufferSize)
   at Utilities.getByteArray(Stream input) in D:\repos\SampleProj\Sample\Helpers\CH.cs:line 238
   at Utilities.getImageFromUrl(String url) in D:\repos\SampleProj\Sample\Helpers\CH.cs:line 178
```

I am guessing this maybe because I am not using locks? I am unsure whether to use locks within a `Parallel.ForEach` loop.

Comment: There isn't enough code to tell what's going wrong. If `input` is a shared stream, then your code is clearly wrong, locks or no locks. If each thread is getting its own `input`, then the problem might be that the remote server does not approve of you doing however many requests are being done in parallel.

Comment: @JeroenMostert `input` is not a shared stream

Comment: You code should show where the connection/http requests are done. Do you know how many simultaneous requests you're launching? Maybe some server will block those if there are a lot...

Comment: @MananKapoor Could you provide more code or full code ?

Comment: _"input is not a shared stream"_ - it is according to your code.

Comment: @XouDo Updated the code !

Comment: @MananKapoor `Parallel.ForEach` is simply *not* meant for IO operations. It's meant for data parallelism - processing lots of in-memory data. Using it for IO this is a bug. You're freezing all CPU cores simply waiting for IO to complete. HttpWebRequest is a wrapper over HttpClient in .NET Core, which means your code is highly inefficient. HttpClient can post Stream contents too, which means you could avoid loading data in memory.

Comment: Could you try passing the `new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 };` as the second argument of the `Parallel.ForEach` method, and see if it helps at preventing the error?

Answer (score 2):

According to [another question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2582070/3608483), here are the potential causes for *An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.* :

> - You are sending malformed data to the application (which could include sending an HTTPS request to an HTTP server)
> - The network link between the client and server is going down for some reason
> - You have triggered a bug in the third-party application that caused it to crash
> - The third-party application has exhausted system resources

Since only some of your requests are affected, I think we can exclude the first one. This can be, of course, a network issue, and in that case, this would happend from time to time depending on the quality of the netwok between you and the server.

Unless you find indication of an AzureStorage's bug from other users, there is a high probability your call are consuming too much of the remote server's resources (connections/data) at the same time. Servers and proxy have limitation on how much connections they can handle at the same time (especially from the same client machine).

Depending on the size of your `listSkills` list, your code may launch a **big number of request in parallel** (as much as your thread pool can), possibly flooding the server.

You could at least limit the number of parallel task launch using `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` like this :

```
Parallel.ForEach(listSkills,
    new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 },
    item =>
    {
         // some business logic
         var b = getImageFromUrl(item.Url);
         Stream ms = new MemoryStream(b);
    
         saveImage(ms);
         // more business logic
    });
```

Comment: Or the mix of async and sync code leaves streams and tasks orphaned, resulting in attempts to read even after the root operation completed. Using `Parallel.ForEach` makes this a lot more likely because it's simply not meant for async operations. Limiting the DOP won't fix this fundamental problem. Even with DOP=1 you could still get errors

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You're right. HttpRequest can be launched async'ly easily so there's not much gain at launching it in parallel loop. But at least the OP can test if their error is cause by the high degree of parallelism.  As the connection is *closed by remote host*, it doesn't seem to fail because of local machine memory consideration (though ther may be some anyway).

Answer (score 2):

You can control parallelism like:

```
listSkills.AsParallel()
                .Select(item => {/*Your Logic*/ return item})
                .WithDegreeOfParallelism(10)
                .Select(item =>
                  {
                      getImageFromUrl(item.url);
                      saveImage(your_stream);
                      return item;
                  });
```

But `Parallel.ForEach` is not good for `IO` because it's designed for `CPU-intensive` tasks, if you use it for `IO-bound` operations specially making web requests you may waste thread pool thread blocked while waiting for response.

You use asynchronous web request methods like `HttpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync`, in the other side you can also use thread synchronization constructs for that, as ab example using `Semaphore`, the `Semaphore` is like queue, it allows `X` threads to pass, and the rest should wait until one of busy threads will finish it's work.
First make your `getStream` method as `async` like (this is not good solution but can be better):

```
public static async Task getImageFromUrl(SemaphoreSlim semaphore, string url)
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = null; 
        byte[] b = null;
        request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        using (var response = await request.GetResponseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            // your logic
        } 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // handle exp
    }
    finally
    {
        // release
        semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

and then:

```
using (var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(10))
{
    foreach (var url in urls)
    {
        // await here until there is a room for this task
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();
        tasks.Add(getImageFromUrl(semaphore, url));
    }
    // await for the rest of tasks to complete
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

You should not use the `Parallel` or `Task.Run` instead you can have an `async` handler method like:

```
public async Task handleResponse(Task<HttpResponseMessage> response)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await response;
    //Process your data
}
```

and then use `Task.WhenAll` like:

```
Task[] requests = myList.Select(l => getImageFromUrl(l.Id))
                        .Select(r => handleResponse(r))
                        .ToArray(); 
await Task.WhenAll(requests);
```

at the end there are several solution for your scenario but forget `Parallel.Foreach` instead use optimized solution.

Comment: None of this code is necessary. HttpWebRequest shouldn't be used in the first place, it's just a compatibility wrapper over HttpClient in .NET Core. Semaphores over async code are a bad idea too. There are already better constructs both at the low level (task schedulers) middle (channels) and high level (Parallel.ForEachAsync and Dataflow)

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with this code:

- `Parallel.ForEach` is meant for data parallelism, not IO. The code is freezing all CPU cores waiting for IO to complete
- HttpWebRequest is a wrapper over HttpClient in .NET Core. Using HttpWebRequest is inefficient and far more complex than needed.
- HttpClient can post retrieve or post stream contents which means there's no reason to load stream contents in memory. HttpClient is thread-safe and meant to be reused too.

There are several ways to execute many IO operations concurrently in .NET Core.

**.NET 6**

In the current Long-Term-Support version of .NET, .NET 6, this can be done using [Parallel.ForEachAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync?view=net-6.0). Scott Hanselman [shows how easy it is to use it for API calls](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/parallelforeachasync-in-net-6)

You can retrieve the data directly with `GetBytesAsync` :

```
record CopyRequest(Uri sourceUri,Uri blobUri);
...
var requests=new List<CopyRequest>();
//Load some source/target URLs

var client=new HttpClient();
await Parallel.ForEachAsync(requests,async req=>{
    var bytes=await client.GetBytesAsync(req.sourceUri);
    var blob=new CloudAppendBlob(req.targetUri);
    await blob.UploadFromByteArrayAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
});
```

A better option would be to retrieve the data as a stream and send it directly to the blob :

```
await Parallel.ForEachAsync(requests,async req=>{
    var response=await client.GetAsync(req.sourceUri, 
                       HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
    using var sourceStream=await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    var blob=new CloudAppendBlob(req.targetUri);
    await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(sourceStream);
});
```

`HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead` causes `GetAsync` to return as soon as the response headers are received, without buffering any of the response data.

**.NET 3.1**

In older .NET Core versions (which are reaching End-of-Life in a few months) you can use eg an ActionBlock with a Degree-Of-Parallelism greater than 1:

```
var options=new ExecuteDataflowBlockOptions{ MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8};

var copyBlock=new ActionBlock<CopyRequest>(async req=>{
    var response=await client.GetAsync(req.sourceUri, 
                       HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
    using var sourceStream=await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    var blob=new CloudAppendBlob(req.targetUri);
    await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(sourceStream);
}, options);
```

The block classes in the TPL Dataflow library can be used to construct processing pipelines similar to a shell script pipeline, with each block piping its output to the next block.