# ASP.NET C# websocket exception when send close message

Tags: c#, asp.net

why when i send close message to  to webscoket it crashed with
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 'The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.'

Also how to make websocket send message continuously when receives  one message from client a keep it listen to close message from another task or thread.

i try to add CloseOutputAsync and CloseAsyn and i got same exception.
i added a task that only listen  for websocket to close it but also same exception.

UPDATE :

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment      env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            ``if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }


#if NoOptions
            // <snippet_UseWebSockets>
            app.UseWebSockets();
            // </snippet_UseWebSockets>
#endif
#if UseOptions
            // <snippet_UseWebSocketsOptions>
            var webSocketOptions = new WebSocketOptions()
            {
                KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120),
            };

            app.UseWebSockets(webSocketOptions);
            // </snippet_UseWebSocketsOptions>
#endif

#if UseOptionsAO
            // <snippet_UseWebSocketsOptionsAO>
            var webSocketOptions = new WebSocketOptions()
            {
                KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120),
            };
            webSocketOptions.AllowedOrigins.Add("https://client.com");
            webSocketOptions.AllowedOrigins.Add("https://www.client.com");

            app.UseWebSockets(webSocketOptions);
            // </snippet_UseWebSocketsOptionsAO>
#endif
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls13;
            redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(Configuration["RedisConnect"]);
            db = redis.GetDatabase();
            endPoint = redis.GetEndPoints();
            server = redis.GetServer(endPoint[0], Configuration["RedisConnect"]);
            // <snippet_AcceptWebSocket>
            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                if (context.Request.Path == "/ws")
                 {
                    if (context.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
                    {
                        using (WebSocket webSocket = await context.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync())
                        {
                            await Echo(context, webSocket);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    await next();
                }
         app.UseFileServer();
            });
             private async Task Echo(HttpContext context,WebSocket webSocket) 
        {
            var buffer=new byte[1024*4];
            var result=await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);
            if (result != null) 
            {
                while (!result.CloseStatus.HasValue) 
                {
                    string msg=Encoding.UTF8.GetString(new ArraySegment<byte> (buffer,0,result.Count));
                    await webSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("servrSays")),result.MessageType,result.EndOfMessage,System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);
                    result=await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);
                }
            }
            await webSocket.CloseAsync(result.CloseStatus.Value,result.CloseStatusDescription,System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);
        }
```

Comment: Could you provide some code? What version of tls do you use? What versions of tls are supported by remote host?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582036/an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host)

Comment: sorry  the exception  is System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 'The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.'

Comment: Please provide code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I added the code to question