# Anypoint Studio OJDBC (Oracle ODBC) Connector Issues

Tags: netsuite, mulesoft, mule4, anypoint-studio, ojdbc

I'm very new to MuleSoft and so far I have used the standard Salesforce and NetSuite connectors to create simple flows.
I have been trying to configure the OJDBC driver to enable direct NetSuite queries for more complicated flows that I'm working on, however, I haven't been able to get the OJDBC to work.
I've used versions 8, 10, and 11.

This is my setup:
[version and dependency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDDQ0.jpg)
[connection details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFBqJ.jpg)

Please let me know if I haven't provided enough information and what else would be helpful to know :)

This is my setup:
[version and dependency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDDQ0.jpg)
[connection details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFBqJ.jpg)

Please let me know if I haven't provided enough information and what else would be helpful :)

Error log:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:276) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:245) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:223) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:353) ~[?:?]
    at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.read(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:174) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO.doSocketRead(NSProtocolNIO.java:555) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readNIOPacket(NIOPacket.java:403) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolNIO.java:127) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:340) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1596) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:588) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:793) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:57) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:747) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:562) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677) ~[java.sql:?]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:189) ~[java.sql:?]
    at org.mule.db.commons.shaded.internal.domain.connection.enhydra.wrappers.EnhydraWrapperUtils.getSecureConnectionIfPossible(EnhydraWrapperUtils.java:100) ~[mule-db-connector-1.14.4-mule-plugin.jar:?]
    ... 70 more
ERROR 2023-10-11 16:35:09,980 [[MuleRuntime].uber.12: [ojdbc-ns].ojdbc-nsFlow.BLOCKING @67c0f299] [processor: ojdbc-nsFlow/processors/0; event: f15e0d80-67f7-11ee-90c8-806d970dc42d] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.exception.OnErrorContinueHandler: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Cannot get connection for URL jdbc:oracle:thin:@3809881.connect.api.netsuite.com:1708 : IO Error: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host, Authentication lapse 0 ms.
Element               : ojdbc-nsFlow/processors/0 @ ojdbc-ns:ojdbc-ns.xml:17 (Select)
Element DSL           : <db:select doc:name="Select" doc:id="44427429-1100-4a4b-a0c4-b596bc642a14" config-ref="Database_Config">
<db:sql><![CDATA[
select id from accountt
]]></db:sql>
</db:select>
Error type            : DB:CONNECTIVITY
FlowStack             : at ojdbc-nsFlow(ojdbc-nsFlow/processors/0 @ ojdbc-ns:ojdbc-ns.xml:17 (Select))

  (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

Comment: Hello Danyal, Reading the error message "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" it appears that the connection with DB host is getting closed.

To rule out if this is a MuleSoft DB connector issue or an issue on the DB host side, are you able to connect with any other JDBC client (such as DBeaver- https://dbeaver.io/ ) outside MuleSoft? 

Also, enabe TCP Capture to understand which side is closing the connection (https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-capture-network-traffic-between-two-systems) and please check with your DB team if they could provide insights.

Comment: Additionally, in case it helps, please check this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582036/an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host

Comment: Please **do not** post images of code, data, logs, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. Reserve the use of images for diagrams or rendering bugs or things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Code or sample data in images can't be copied in order to search about a problem or reproduce it. For more details read the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557).  XML text should be used for Mule configurations and dependencies.

Comment: Note that (ODBC)[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Database_Connectivity] is a complete different thing than OJDBC and JDBC-ODBC bridge.