# Receiving "connection was forcibly closed" error in the ActiveMQ Artemis log

Tags: activemq-artemis

I'm suddenly receiving this error in the ActiveMQ Artemis log then MQ has been stopped. We are connecting from WebSphere to Artemis active using WebSphere JMS configuration given queue name in the WAS itself.

```
2023-11-04 18:52:17,673 WARN [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ212037: Connection failure to null has been detected: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host [code=GENERIC_EXCEPTION]
2023-11-04 18:52:17,673 WARN [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ212037: Connection failure to /172.16.6.42:50372 has been detected: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host [code=GENERIC_EXCEPTION]
2023-11-04 18:52:17,673 WARN [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ212037: Connection failure to /172.16.6.53:50273 has been detected: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host [code=GENERIC_EXCEPTION]
2023-11-04 18:52:17,673 WARN [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ212037: Connection failure to null has been detected: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host [code=GENERIC_EXCEPTION]
2023-11-04 18:52:17,673 WARN [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ212037: Connection failure to /172.16.6.51:50237 has been detected: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host [code=GENERIC_EXCEPTION]
```

Comment: This looks like a network issue in your environment. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582036/an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host) might be helpful.