# I can't connect to a specific server, but the error message is very vague

Tags: java, server, connection, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I was invited to play on a modded minecraft server by a friend. However, a few seconds after logging into the server, I get kicked with the message `Internal Exception: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`

I've confirmed that the mods and forge version I'm using match with the server, as it uses an official modpack, and I have no problem joining other servers with the same mods.

The server is located in Australia whereas I am located in Sweden, I suspected this might be a cause but both my friend and some other players on the server are also from Sweden, and I'm very confident in my internet strength.

These are most of the things I've already tried after looking for solutions:

- Restarting the game (many times)
- Restarting my PC (also several times)
- Restarting my router.
- Changing the render distance to 2 so packets are reduced.
- Clearing my DNS cache.
- Changing my Java PATH to use java 16 (was 18 before).
- Enabling native sandbox.
- Disabling firewall.
- Creating a new registry value (not sure what this is but it didn't work).

The server also uses 2 different IP addresses, and Minecraft has 2 different ways to connect to a server (adding it and direct connect), and I've tried all 4 of those combinations after all the solutions above.

I can still not join the server after all of that. I'm frankly lost on what else I can do, because the error message can just mean so many different things. If anyone has a clue, I would really appreciate the help.

EDIT: The server owners are thankfully great people, and have decided to switch host (not only because of me, but still very nice of them). So far I'm not having any connection issues with the new host, but they haven't ported over world and player files yet, so I'll have to wait and see if it still works after that.
For now, the problem is "solved", but the root cause has yet to be identified.

Comment: your friend's server might have a different forge (server) version than your (client) version. additionally, their router might be the source of the issue. can other people connect to their server?

Comment: @Pew I should have been more specific. It's not my friend's server, they only invited me. The server has dozens of players, and they use an official modpack so there will be no differences in forge or mod versions. The server is also in Australia, whereas I'm in sweden (but so is my friend and some other players).
I'll update my question to reflect this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582036/an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host)

Comment: @user207421 Not that I can tell, I haven't read all the answers but it all seems to be about code solutions and I am currently only using a software, so I won't have any possibility of editing it. It's also about C# rather than Java which is what Minecraft uses.
The first answer does point at a few of the possibilities of what could potential cause the error, I believe I've seen this before in fact, but it doesn't help me solve the problem.